# OAuth error while sending the access token in header

Tags: oauth, jira-rest-api, php-curl

I am getting this error :

> "{"errorMessages":["You do not have the permission to see the specified issue.","Login Required"],"errors":{}}" {"errorMessages":["You do not have the permission to see the specified issue.","Login Required"],"errors":{}}

while I am trying to fetch an issue from the JIRA.

For fetching the issue I am using CURL in PHP. The code is below:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(<br/>
CURLOPT_PORT => "8080",<br/>
CURLOPT_URL => "http://url/rest/api/latest/issue/issue id",<br/>
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,<br/>
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",<br/>
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,<br/>
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,<br/>
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,<br/>
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",<br/>
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",<br/>
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Accept: application/json',<br/>
'Content-Type: application/json','authorization: Bearer access_token'<br/>
),<br/>
));
```

The access token is working fine as I am able to get the response through insomnia. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Obviously, you are not configuring an access token or any other way of login

Comment: it should look something like: Authorization: Bearer N2FmNzhhNGM...